# Need a help for sort in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hi I want to sort a table .The field contains numbers,alphabets and numbers with alphabets ie,

```
1
2
1a
11a
a
6a
b
```

I want to sort this to,

```
1
1a
2
6a
11a
a
b
```

My code is,

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY CAST(st AS SIGNED), st
```

But the result is,

```
a
b
1
1a
2
6a
11a
```

I found this code in this url

```
"http://www.mpopp.net/2006/06/sorting-of-numeric-values-mixed-with-alphanumeric-values/"
```

Anyone please help me

Comment: First of all check what CAST is returning. I think it will convert st to a number. Run this query: SELECT CAST(st AS SIGNED) FROM t

Comment: @asim-ishaq It returns numbers only.The result is 1,12,11,6,1,2,0,0

Comment: for alphabets it will return 0 so they always come on top. we have to think of a different logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do your required sort order, even in the presence of `0` in the table;

```
SELECT * FROM t 
ORDER BY 
  st REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]].*', 
  st+0, 
  st
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a61a/1).

- As a first sort criteria, it sorts *anything that starts with a letter* after anything that doesn't. That's what the regexp does.
- As a second sort criteria it sorts by the numerical value the string starts with (`st+0` adds 0 to the numerical part the string starts with and returns an int)
- As a last resort, it sorts by the string itself to get the alphabetical ones in order.

Comment: yes this is the correct answer, +1 :) i didn't consider the fact that there could be some 0

Comment: @Vivek Added a small explanation, let me know if I need to clarify :)

Comment: what does it mean starts "with a letter last" ?

Comment: @Vivek Sorry, added emphasis, it means anything that starts with a letter, it will put last in the sort order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY
  st+0=0, st+0, st
```

Using `st+0` the varchar column will be casted to int. Ordering by `st+0=0` will put alphanumeric rows at the bottom (st+0=0 will be 1 if the string starts with an alphanumeric character, oterwise it will be 0)

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d51df/1).

Comment: @NavaneethaNair you're welcome but please check Joachim Isaksson answer, his answer works even if there are some 0 in your field, while mine will put 0 at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting this output is that all the character like 'a', 'b' etc are converted to '0' and if you use order by ASC it will appear at the top.

```
SELECT CAST(number AS SIGNED) from tbl
```

is returning

```
1
2
1
11
0
6
0
```

Look at this fiddle:- [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e183/11)

Answer (score -3):

I did small change in your query -

```
SELECT *, CAST(st AS SIGNED) as casted_column
FROM t
ORDER BY casted_column ASC, st ASC
```

this should work. 
in theory your syntax should work but not sure why mysql doesn't accept these methods after from tag. 
so created temp field and then sorted that one .

This should work as per my experience,  and you can check it.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceedc/1)

Comment: It returns numbers only.The casted_column contains is 0,0,1,2,6,11,12

Comment: Not working for 'a', 'b' etc. It is not working for pure numeric date.

Comment: His need is both alphanumeric,characters as well as pure numeric. Read his question carefully.

Comment: Navaneetha --  use original values form database not casted.  Casted we use only for sorting not for final ussage.